# How to diagonalize this matrix??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have this matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\det(A-λI)=0$

I get 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1-λ & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 1-λ & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3-λ \\ 
\end{vmatrix} = 0 $$

After simplifying this determinant, I get $(λ^2-9)(λ+1)=0$.

Is this right? So $λ=3, -3, -1$.

Where do I go now?

I've seen $D=P^{-1}AP$. I would greatly appreciate an explanation of this!

Thanks.

Comment: Find three linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Construct a matrix of normalized eigenvectors in the columns.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to put -1. Oops.

Comment: @Amzoti, so when is the matrix actually diagonalized... I'm not sure I get that?

Comment: I figured it out before you explained it, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the eigen vectors corresponding to the eigen values.. Place the eigen values as columns ..(there will be three distinct eigen vectors).. This will form your $P$, $D$ will be the eigen values

Answer (score 1):

Once you've found the eigenvalues, find their corresponding eigenvectors, as an example

- Eigenvalue with respect to $\lambda_1 = -1$
  $$(A - \lambda I)v = 0 \implies \begin{pmatrix}2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Which gives us $$\begin{cases} 2v_1 + 2v_2 = 0\\-2v_3 = 0 \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} v_2 = -v_1 \\v_3 = 0 \end{cases}$$

Thus the $\ker (A - \lambda_1 I)  =\Big\{a \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix} ; a \in \mathbb R\Big\}$. We may choose $ v = \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Once you have found all eigenvectors to the distinct eigenvalues you will get

$$D =  \begin{pmatrix}| & | & |\\u & v & w\\| & | & |\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}| & | & |\\u & v & w\\| & | & |\end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

this is diagonal block matrix. you can see that $-3$ is an eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector is $(0,0,1)^T.$  the matrix $\pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}$ is a projection matrix onto $(1,1)^T$ followed by magnification by a factor of $3.$ so the eigenvalues are $3, 0$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $(1,1)^T$ and $(1, -1)^T.$

the eigenvalues of the matrix are $1, 3, 0$ and the corresponding orthogonal eigenvectors are
$0,0,1)^T, (1,1, 0)^T$ and $(1, -1, 0)^T.$